# Can't communicate with service using DNS in service fabric

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, azure-service-fabric

I'm trying to get a stateless service to send a value to another, just to achieve communication between services by using the DNS-service in service fabric. I've tested both applications with postman, and they work fine. I'm following [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-dnsservice) where it seems pretty straight forward to do this.

**The DNS-service is enabled:** [image: DNS-service is running]

**The stateless service has a DNS-name:**[image]
**The DNS-name is configured in the ApplicationManifest.xml**

```xml
<Service Name="SocketService" 
 ServiceDnsName="SocketService.TimeSeriesActorApplication" 
 ServicePackageActivationMode="ExclusiveProcess">
    <StatelessService ServiceTypeName="SocketServiceType" 
     InstanceCount="[SocketService_InstanceCount]">
       <SingletonPartition />
   </StatelessService>
</Service>
```

I then try to send a http get to the service, just like in the tutorial.

```cs
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
 client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://socketservice.timeseriesactorapplication:8712/api/");
 var response = await client.GetAsync("values");
}
```

But I get an exception:

> WebException: The remote name could not be resolved: 'socketservice.timeseriesactorapplication'

This happens both when I use port 8080 like the tutorial suggests, and when I use the port I specify in ServiceManifest.xml.

```xml
<Endpoints>
  <Endpoint Protocol="http" Name="ServiceEndpoint" Type="Input" Port="8712" />
</Endpoints>
```

What am I missing here?

**Update:**
Using localhost instead of dns-name also works fine.

**Issue on Github: [Unable to resolve service DNS name #332](https://github.com/Azure/service-fabric-issues/issues/332)**

Comment: Just went through the tutorial with no issues. Where is you client initiating the call running?

Comment: Both are stateless services running in a local service fabric cluster. I'm doing a get-request with postman to one of them that again is trying to reach the other one via a second get request.

Comment: When you say using localhost - is that also service to service communication?

Comment: Yes. Using localhost instead of the DNS-name I'm specifying works when communicating between the services

Comment: Recommend you open an issue here: https://github.com/Azure/service-fabric-issues/issues/ - I'll ping some engineers to help troubleshoot your issue. Seems no obvious reason why this should not work.

Answer (score 0):

I see you are running service fabric 5.6.210. The recent 5.6.220 release (https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azureservicefabric/2017/06/20/release-of-sdk-2-6-220-and-runtime-5-6-220-refresh-for-windows/) contains some fixes for the DNS service. Note that even though I am running 5.6.220, I have noticed that the DNS name resolution does not always seem to start working straight away after deployment on my local machine (I have to redeploy or wait a few minutes). If you are running locally you can test the name resolution in a terminal window - just ping your service's DNS name.

Comment: Updated to the newest version, but still can't get it working. Pinging my service's DNS name doesn't work either.

Comment: Try flushing the DNS cache (ipconfig /flushdns) before you ping. Also, it appears to me that the DNS service works by running a DNS server locally on your machine and adding your machine to the top of the list of DNS servers for your primary adapter. Thus if you do ipconfig /all you should see your primary adapter IP address at the top of the list of DNS servers for that adapter. If it is not there, something is probably wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by using ipconfig /flushdns to refresh DNS.
I also found that local IP is the first DNS server in my DNS chain.